# CISCO UCS Event ID 153 The IO operation at logical block address for Disk 2 (PDO name: \Device\MPIODisk1) was retried

Tags: windows-event-log

On my Cisco UCS blade, the windows system event log just started being flooded with these Event ID 153 messages. The OS is Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard. The SAN admin says that there are no errors in the HP 3par SAN logs and that the ports on the switch also show no errors.  My thought was that new hotfixes were applied but the last update applied was over 2 months ago.   The error is happening for multiple drive letters.  Disk busy is at 100% and Disk Read bytes/sec is less than 1 MB/sec. There is no antivirus running on the server.  It is a dedicated SQL Server 2014 database server.   SQL Server also has the message in its logs SQL Server has encountered 1 occurrence(s) of I/O requests taking longer than 15 seconds to complete on its files.  Since this is the only server that is experiencing this, my suspicion is that something changed in the MPIO driver settings.  I am looking for suggestions on other possible causes for this error message and how to resolve it.